# How to delete a range of rows from a cell array using cellfun, matlab

Tags: matlab, cell, delete-row

I have a 1x3 cell with

```
timepositionrawdata = {time, lat, lon};
% Extract every fourth instance of the raw data
time = timepositionrawdata{1,1}(1:4:end);
lat = timepositionrawdata{1,2}(1:4:end);
lon = timepositionrawdata{1,3}(1:4:end);
timepositionrawdata = {time, lat, lon};

% Delete and add appropriate rows to match image sequence times
timepositionrawdata{1}(278,:) = [];
timepositionrawdata{2}(278,:) = [];
timepositionrawdata{3}(278,:) = [];

timepositionrawdata = timepositionrawdata{1}([1:281, 281:end],:);
timepositionrawdata = timepositionrawdata{2}([1:281, 281:end],:);
timepositionrawdata = timepositionrawdata{3}([1:281, 281:end],:);
```

I would like to be able to delete particular rows in the whole cell.  How do you use cellfun to do this?

Comment: Please provide a sample cell array and explain/show  how exactly do you want to remove your data?

Comment: Are time, lat and lon of the same size? If so a matrix would be the appropriate data structure, it a cell.

Comment: Yes.  Time, lat and lon are all the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to write a function that processes one cell correctly, then use `cellfun` to apply it to the cell array.

```
function time = process_one_cell(time)
time = time(1:4:end);
time(278, :) = [];
time = time([1:281, 281:end], :); % I'm not sure why you're doing this, looks kind of pointless. 
end
```

And then call the function as follows

```
timepositionrawdata = cellfun(@process_one_cell, timepositionrawdata, 'UniformOutput', 0);
% or if you prefer to be more verbose
timepositionrawdata = cellfun(@(x) process_one_cell(x), timepositionrawdata, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

Comment: I need to add or copy a row to match the time sequence for data from another source.  I'm matching ocean data collected from a moving ship to data collected from a stationary buoy, whilst synching the time.

Comment: Please be more explicit with what you want to do: give an example input/output. I don't understand what you want to achieve from your description.